# Recovering data about the toric fan from minimal information

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, toric-geometry

I am a physics grad student studying toric diagrams since they naturally arise in the description of certain gauge theories obtained by compactifying M/F-theory on Calabi-Yau 3-folds. In this context, the Calabi-Yau manifold is elliptically fibered, and the base of the fibration is a nonsingular two-dimensional toric variety.

This means -- as I understand -- that the toric fan describing the base is obtainable by succesive blowups of the Hirzebruch surface or $\mathbb{P}^2$.

In the physics context, the toric fan of the base is the dual diagram of the so called ``(p, q) web'' diagram. So, given a web diagram describing a field theory on the physics side, I can construct the dual diagram -- which is just the toric fan of the base.

However, in doing so, I do not have the information about the coordinates of the vertices (i.e. one-dimensional cones, which correspond to divisors) of the toric fan.

My question is, given such a diagram with the only additional information being that it describes the base of an elliptically fibered Calabi-Yau 3-fold, can I somehow reconstruct the "coordinates" of the vertices relative to any vertex as an origin? I thought there should be a simple way by experimenting with blow-ups of the basic two-dimensional toric surfaces, but none of those blowups seem to naturally reproduce the toric fan I am interested in.

So in more simple terms: **given a toric fan (a diagram in two dimensions on a plane), how do I reconstruct the coordinates of its vertices (relative to some chosen coordinate frame)?**

Are there any additional constraints that I am missing?

I need this information because I want to compute all the triple intersection numbers and one of the first steps is to derive linear equivalences between divisors, and compute the Mori cone generators.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If you have a fan, then the set of divisors are given by the edges of this fan. And then from this you can compute the intersection pairing.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet, thanks for your reply. Maybe I wasn't being precise. I know what the fan "looks" like. I know it has $n$ divisors (which I thought correspond to vertices, e.g. page 16 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1310.pdf). But beyond the visual appearance, I don't know anything more. In this article, the author describes an algorithm to compute the intersection numbers which seems to rely on a knowledge of the coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: Ok I can try to make an answer, tell me if this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more a comment that an answer. For toric surface, the situation is pretty nice. Let me assume for simplicity that $X$ is smooth, that is for every cone $\sigma \in \Sigma$, $\sigma = \{v_1,v_2\}$ is smooth, meaning that $v_1,v_2$ generate the lattice $\Bbb Z^2$.

Now, we have an exact sequence $$ 0 \to \Bbb Z^2 \to \text{TDiv}(X) \to Pic(X) \to 0 $$

Where $Pic(X)$ is the Picard group of $X$, that is the group of divisor modulo linear equivalence. The first map simply send a character $\chi^m$ to its divisor $D = \text{div}(\chi(m))$.

Now, for computing self intersection of a divisor $D_{\rho}$ with primitive vector $v_1$ (this means that $\Bbb R_+ v_1 = \rho$ and $v_1 \in \Bbb Z^2$) corresponding to an edge is simple : such divisor is between two cones $\sigma = cone(u,v_1)$ and $\sigma' = cone(v_1,w)$. Then since by hypothesis the cone are smooth, $u + w = -a v_1$ for some $a \in \Bbb Z$, and we have $a = (D_{\rho})^2$. Other intersection numbers are fairly simple : $D_i \cdot D_j = 1$ if $i,j$ share a cone and $0$ else.

More informations can be found [here](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~bonavero/articles/ecoledete/ecoledete.html), in particular there are notes about toric divisors, and later there is also toric Mori theory. The book by Cox, Little and Schenck is also an excellent reference.

There is a simple formula for the intersection of a $T$-invariant curve $C$ and a $T$-invariant divisor: this is proposition 6.3.8 in the book by Cox,Schenck and Little.

> **Proposition** : Let $C$ a $T$-invariant curve corresponding to the wall $\tau = \sigma \cap \sigma'$. Let $D$ a Cartier divisor with Cartier data $m_{\sigma}$. Then, if $u \in \sigma'$ maps to a minimal generator of $N/\Bbb R \tau$. Then, $$ D \cdot C = \langle m_{\sigma} - m_{\sigma'},u \rangle $$

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Hemelsoet! The toric variety corresponding to my situation is of the form $(\mathbb{C}^8 - F_{\Sigma})/(\mathbb{C}^\star)^5$. There are 8 divisors, and I know what the exclusion set $F_{\Sigma}$ is in terms of the 8 coordinates $(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_8)$ - its just a finite union of codimension-2 spaces. So the variety is a 3-dimensional complex space. The Calabi-Yau condition then lets us focus on a surface.  So in this case, does what you said also apply? Also, $a = (D_\rho)^2$ but I don't know what $D_\rho$ is. What does the notation $\mathbb{R}_+ v_1 = \rho$ mean?

Comment: Hi, for your more specific situation I can try to think more (but I'm a bit in a rush right now). If $\rho$ is an edge of a fan then there is a $T$-invariant associated divisor $D_{\rho}$. $\rho = \Bbb R_+ v_1$ means that $v_1$ lies on the edge $\rho$. (I can try to provide more details and think to your specific situation later).